# Using DataFrame#loc with arguments of trivially different types

Tags: python, pandas

Let `df` be a `DataFrame` with an index of dtype `x`. Due to implicit type conversions, I end up having to call `df.loc(n)`, where `n` was implicitly converted from `x` to a trivially different type `y`. Most commonly this happens with `int` converted to `float`. For example:

```
In [35]: df = DataFrame([[1, 2.0]]).set_index(0, drop=False); df
Out[35]: 
   0  1
0  
1  1  2

In [36]: df[0]
Out[36]: 
0
1    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [37]: df.loc[1]
Out[37]: 
0    1
1    2
Name: 1, dtype: float64

In [38]: df.loc[df.loc[1][0]]
[...]
KeyError: 1.0
```

As you can see, the value in the first column - which also serves as the index - was implicitly converted from `int64` to `float64` when it was returned from the `df.loc[1]` operation. Unfortunately once that happens, I can no longer use this value for further `df.loc` operations, since the index is still `int64`, and looking up a `float64` value in an `int64` index will always fail.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly recast when doing your `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.loc[1].astype('int64')[0]]
0    1
1    2
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Or, more generally:

```
df.loc[df.loc[2].astype(df[0].dtype)[0]]
```